# Where to deploy jars for a Domino Agent

Tags: java, deployment, jar, lotus-domino, agent

I've an agent that use Axis jars.
Which are the alternatives for these jars deploying?

If I put them into *lib/ext* folder on server, everything works fine, but I wouldn't deploy "by hand" all jars in every production server.

If I put them into *Archive* agent section, also into *WEB-INF/lib* project folder, I always have a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to deploy a jar into *notesdata/domino/java* folder and modified notes.ini *JavaUserClasses* variable to point to this jar, but same error!

**UPDATE 2**

As suggested, I put the jar (**axiom-api-1.2.8.jar**) into agent *Archive*, but still the same error

```
HTTP JVM: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axiom.om.OMNode
HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:70)
HTTP JVM:  at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
HTTP JVM:  at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createBasicConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:337)
HTTP JVM:  at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createDefaultConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:326)
HTTP JVM:  at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:499)
HTTP JVM:  at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
HTTP JVM:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Put the jars into agent's Archive section. That is the right place. You might need some additional jars http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/install.html#Step_2:_Setting_up_the_libraries Have a look at error message *which* class is not found.

Comment: Thanks Knut, take a look at UPDATE 2

Comment: In which sense? axiom-api-1.2.8.jar is not enough? I also need to include other in the agent archive?

Comment: Any other suggestion, Knut?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. If you really put all your jars from *lib/ext* folder to agent's Archives then I have no other ideas what to try. I downloaded axis/axiom and put them into an agent but I can't really test it because of lack of code ... unfortunately error shows at runtime only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right place to put jar is into **agent's Archive section**.

The problem experienced during my test following

```
HTTP JVM: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axiom.om.OMNode
```

doesn't depend on the *axiom-api-1.2.8.jar* absence, but on the absence of the whole jar dependencies.

Infact, including all jars needed, everything work's fine.

Thanks Knut for your suggestion.